# liquibase:updateSQL does not create table schema prefix

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I run `liquibase:updateSQL` with the following parameters on postgres:

```
changelogSchemaName online
defaultCatalogName online
defaultSchemaName online
```

It generates SQL like `CREATE TABLE product` but what I would expect is `CREATE TABLE online.product`

With the generated SQL the users search_path is used so I need to modify my DB before I can use `liquibase:update`

any Ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `outputDefaultCatalog=true` or `outputDefaultSchema=true` maven parameters. That will force the generated SQL to include the default schema even if it is not specified in the changeSet.

Comment: Yes I found that almost working, but not for some custom SQL queries, Stored Procedures, etc. But I guess beside this there is not better way so I mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes, liquibase does no SQL parsing, so whatever is in stored procs and custom queries are passed as as. If you want them included and they change, you may want to look at using changelog parameters in the SQL http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the **catalogName** attribute as described in the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_table.html)?

For example:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="createTable-example">
    <createTable catalogName="online" tableName="product"
        <column name="x" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="y" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```